# What's an efficient way to re-arrange a dataframe according to headers (which are stored in rows)?

Tags: python, dataframe

What would be a efficient pythonic way to re-arrange a dataframe as such? I'm attempting a regression analysis, unfortunately the data is formatted this way. At this time I am using iterations to cut and merge the dataframe (several hundred rows), but it is slow and messy. Thanks!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

# your dataframe example with truncated values and names
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'VarA': ['Var1', 'Var4', 'Var2', 'Var1', 'Var2'],
        'VarB': ['Var2', 'Var5', 'Var3', 'Var2', 'Var3'],
        'VarC': ['Var3', None, 'Var5', 'Var3', 'Var4'],
        'CoefA': [0.658, 0.912, 0.664, 0.006, 0.537],
        'CoefB': [0.749, 0.575, 0.797, 0.728, 0.628],
        'CoefC': [0.517, None, 0.805, 0.172, 0.182]
    },
    index=pd.date_range('5/27/22','5/31/22')[::-1]
)
df
#               VarA    VarB    VarC    CoefA   CoefB   CoefC
# 2022-05-31    Var1    Var2    Var3    0.658   0.749   0.517
# 2022-05-30    Var4    Var5    None    0.912   0.575   NaN
# 2022-05-29    Var2    Var3    Var5    0.664   0.797   0.805
# 2022-05-28    Var1    Var2    Var3    0.006   0.728   0.172
# 2022-05-27    Var2    Var3    Var4    0.537   0.628   0.182
```

Convert each pair of name and value columns into proper format, dropping rows with null values:

```
c_A = (df[['VarA','CoefA']]
       .dropna()
       .pivot(columns='VarA')
       .droplevel(0, axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
c_B = (df[['VarB','CoefB']]
       .dropna()
       .pivot(columns='VarB')
       .droplevel(0, axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
c_C = (df[['VarC','CoefC']]
       .dropna()
       .pivot(columns='VarC')
       .droplevel(0, axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

c_C
#              Var3   Var4   Var5
# 2022-05-27    NaN  0.182    NaN
# 2022-05-28  0.172    NaN    NaN
# 2022-05-29    NaN    NaN  0.805
# 2022-05-31  0.517    NaN    NaN
```

Combine the three dataframes into one, updating values in columns with same name, and then reversing the order of rows to match your desired result:

```
res = c_A.combine_first(c_B).combine_first(c_C).iloc[::-1]
res

#                Var1    Var2    Var3   Var4    Var5
# 2022-05-31    0.658   0.749   0.517    NaN     NaN
# 2022-05-30      NaN     NaN     NaN  0.912   0.575
# 2022-05-29      NaN   0.664   0.797    NaN   0.805
# 2022-05-28    0.006   0.728   0.172    NaN     NaN
# 2022-05-27      NaN   0.537   0.628  0.182     NaN
```

**EDIT, GENERALIZATION TO INDEFINITE/UNKNOWN NUMBER OF COLUMNS:**

```
vprefix = 'Var'
cprefix = 'Coef'

def long_to_wide(df, col_id, vprefix=vprefix, cprefix=cprefix):
    return (
        df[[f'{vprefix}{col_id}',f'{cprefix}{col_id}']]
        .dropna()
        .pivot(columns=f'{vprefix}{col_id}')
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    )

df_dict = {}
for col in df:
    if col.startswith(vprefix):
        vsuffix = col.replace(vprefix,'')
        df_dict[vsuffix] = long_to_wide(df, vsuffix)

res = None
for df_id in df_dict:
    if res is None:
        res = df_dict[df_id]
    else:
        res = res.combine_first(df_dict[df_id])

res = res[::-1]
res
#                Var1    Var2    Var3   Var4    Var5
# 2022-05-31    0.658   0.749   0.517    NaN     NaN
# 2022-05-30      NaN     NaN     NaN  0.912   0.575
# 2022-05-29      NaN   0.664   0.797    NaN   0.805
# 2022-05-28    0.006   0.728   0.172    NaN     NaN
# 2022-05-27      NaN   0.537   0.628  0.182     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'VarA': ['Var1', 'Var4', 'Var2', 'Var1', 'Var2'],
    'VarB': ['Var2', 'Var5', 'Var3', 'Var2', 'Var3'],
    'VarC': ['Var3', None, 'Var5', 'Var3', 'Var4'],
    'CoefA': [0.658, 0.912, 0.664, 0.006, 0.537],
    'CoefB': [0.749, 0.575, 0.797, 0.728, 0.628],
    'CoefC': [0.517, None, 0.805, 0.172, 0.182]},
    index=['2022-05-31', '2022-05-30', '2022-05-29', '2022-05-28','2022-05-27'])

## get all unique values in 'VarA','VarB','VarC'
cols = pd.unique(data[['VarA','VarB','VarC']].dropna().values.flatten())
cols = sorted(cols)

## Crete new dataframe with headers
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

## Parse each row in original data and insert value to new dataframe
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    res.at[idx, row['VarA']] = row['CoefA']
    res.at[idx, row['VarB']] = row['CoefB']
    res.at[idx, row['VarC']] = row['CoefC']

## Remove unwanted columns (None)
res = res[cols]
```

Output:

|  | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | Var5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-31 | 0.658 | 0.749 | 0.517 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-05-30 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.912 | 0.575 |
| 2022-05-29 | NaN | 0.664 | 0.797 | NaN | 0.805 |
| 2022-05-28 | 0.006 | 0.728 | 0.172 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-05-27 | NaN | 0.537 | 0.628 | 0.182 | NaN |

The logic is to iter and parse each row in the original dataframe, then insert the value to corresponding location in the new dataframe (`res` in my code)

p.s. As there is a `None` in `VarC`, there will be a column `None` in `res` with this script, therefore the last line is to only select wanted columns

Comment: Thank you ytung and alexk. I am sorry, I forgot to mention that the possible variables are also indefinite (there could be new variables in the full data frame).

Comment: So you will have indefinite columns?

Comment: yes, indefinite columns.